# Reproducing race conditions: continue all threads except one in gdb

Tags: multithreading, automated-tests, gdb, race-condition

I have found a race condition in my application code and now I am wondering how I could create a test case for it, that can be run as a test script that is determined to trigger a specific effect of the race condition and doesn't require a reproduction code patch and/or a manual gdb session.

The situation is a schoolbook example of a race condition: I have an address A and thread 1 wants to write to its location and thread 2 wants to read from it.

So I was thinking of writing a gdb script for this that breaks when thread 1 is about to write at address A then write some garbage into A, then have all threads continue except for thread 1. Then fire the query that causes thread 2 to guarantee to read the garbage at A and then causes a segmentation fault or something.

I guess this is the reverse of `set scheduler-locking = on`. I was hoping there exist a way to do something like this in a gdb script. But I am afraid there isn't. Hopefully somebody can prove me wrong.

Also I am open to a non-gdb based solution. The main point is that this race condition test, can run automatically without requiring source code modifications. Think of it as an integration test.

Comment: Have you tried [Non-Stop Mode](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Non_002dStop-Mode.html)?

Comment: Thanks that might work. I'll report on it after the weekend.